# Behavior of printf()

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    printf(5 + "Good Morning\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The code prints Morning. Should the code print Morning or should it show undefined behavior?

Comment: What made you to include "undefined behavior" as a possible scenario? What specifically made you suspect UB in this code?

Comment: The answers here already do a good job explaining what is going on but as a rule of thumb, you should avoid having a non-constant format parameter for printf since that makes it harder for the compiler to find type errors. Consider doing `printf("%s", "Good Morning\n" + 5)` instead

Comment: Odd to find that this isn't a dup of numerous questions. Pointer arithmetic seems rare.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should show 'Morning'.

You are using pointer arithmetic - though you appear not to know it! `"Good Morning\n"` is a `char *` pointer to a constant string. You are then adding 5 to this pointer, which advances it by 5 characters. Hence the pointer now points to the 'M' of 'Morning'.

Answer (score 6):

The code is correct since `printf` is defined as:

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

And according to pointers arithmitic `5 + "Good Morning\n"` is a pointer to the first element of `"Morning\n"`. So the statment:

```
printf(5 + "Good Morning\n");
```

has the same result as:

```
printf("Morning\n");
```

Explanation:

```
                     |G|o|o|d| |M|o|r|n|i|n|g|\n|
                      ^         ^
                      |         |
"Good Morning\n" >----          |
       +                        |
       5 >----------------------
```

Comment: It's not entirely equivalent as the binary will still contain the whole string. This might be significant if the function, unlike `printf`, backtracked to bytes prior to the pointer passed - as well as the fact it wastes space in normal circumstances.